# Retrieved data is not in sequence mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to fetch data from mysql database with following code:

```
 $query = "select DISTINCT std_id from messages where staff_id = '$id' ORDER BY messages.msg_id DESC";
         echo $query."\n";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

                 $object = array(
                     "std_id" => $row['std_id']


                );

                array_push($std_list, $object);

            }

        }
```

Result with the same query displaying me this result on phpmyadmin:
[image: Result on phpmyadmin]

And after fetching result it goes out sequence below results output

[image]

Table data is showing below:

[image]

Comment: Please show your table data with column `std_id` and `msg_id`. According to your SQL query, you sort the data by `msg_id` but you just showed us the data `std_id`...

Comment: if you want it ordered by `std_id` why does your query say `ORDER BY messages.msg_id` ?

Comment: @CKWong Hi, I have edit my question and add picture showing my table data. I wants to retrieve unique user id which inserted message in last and then 2nd last onward..

Comment: As mentioned by @Sm

Comment: @smith Thanks man I just edit my query and it fixed issue.

Comment: @CKWong It fixed thanks :)